# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843) with WebView.loadHTMLString

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I use `Swift` and `UIWebView`
`WebView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: nil)` and get an error,

2019-05-08 13:52:58.758899+0800  wallet[439:41398] [] nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3 tls_handshake_continue: [-9807]
2019-05-08 13:52:58.813981+0800  wallet[439:41413] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)

and most of the similar problem use `URLRequest`, different from me,

here is my string

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://**.****.**.***:29843/Pay/order/Order.htm"  method="post">
       <input type="text"  name="merchantName"  value="net">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


here I replace the ip address with *

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


     WebView.loadHTMLString(mystring, baseURL: nil) //mystring'value is above
     WebView.delegate = self

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('frmBankID').submit(); ")

}
```

now my iphone is white-screen, I just want to show the page, don't mind the security at all ,any way to get the page, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple, you have an issue with the hostname `errSSLHostNameMismatch = -9843,  /* peer host name mismatch */` . Are you sure you have the correct url? Is it really https? Is the SSL certificate correct for the domain?

document: https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-40581/lib/SecureTransport.h

Comment: I am sure it 's a  correct url, I am sure  it is  really https,       I am not sure   the SSL certificate correct for the domain ,but on android,we get the page by add the code: @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    webView.getSettings()
                            .setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
                }
                handler.proceed();

            }

Comment: so, it also doesn't work on android? Then you have a backend issue if that's the case?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like you are doing a band-aid solution on android, I think its better to fix the backend configuration issue rather than relying on that solution so that it wont throw an sslError on both platforms

Comment: thanks, because we just make some test and it's a test envirement,and the backend knows the question and don't want to solve, and we have to show the page on iphone and android,  I think there are some way to skip the problem and show the page. If we can't see the page,the manager can't sure if  we have finished coding. thanks.

Comment: Then try catching the error in iOS. Access the error object via the `navigationDelegate` and `func webView(WKWebView, didFail: WKNavigation!, withError: Error)` or `func webView(WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation: WKNavigation!, withError: Error)` delegate methods and see if you can get the html from there. Though I am not sure if it is possible

Comment: thanks,but i used UIWebView,not WKWebView ,then  I add webviewdelegate method  :  func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,didFailLoadWithError error: Error){
        print("************");
    }  it didn't print, It seemed that it can't catch the error